# Marking up an asterisk with <kbd>

Tags: support, markdown, kbd

I've experienced a problem with `<kbd>` tag and the asterisk `*` on Stack Overflow.

How to reproduce:

1. `<kbd>*</kbd> bug <kbd>*</kbd>`

   which provides:  bug
2. `<kbd>**</kbd> bug <kbd>*</kbd>`
   which provides: <kbd>**</kbd> bug <kbd>*</kbd>
3. `<kbd>**</kbd> bug <kbd>**</kbd>`
   which provides  bug

Example without the issue:

<kbd>/</kbd> bug <kbd>*</kbd>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to escape the asterisks since they are involved in formatting in markdown.

```
<kbd>\*</kbd>
```

<kbd>*</kbd>

```
<kbd>\*\*</kbd>
```

<kbd>**</kbd>

Same applies to <kbd>_</kbd> if you want to show the <kbd>_</kbd> key.